# Error when sending post request in Android

Tags: java, android, http

I have this method :

```
public String post(String urlParameters, String url) throws IOException{
        URL obj = new URL(url);
        HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) obj.openConnection();
        con.setRequestMethod("POST");
        con.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Chrome");
        con.setRequestProperty("Accept-Language", "en-US,en;q=0.5");
        con.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        con.setDoOutput(true);
        DataOutputStream wr = new DataOutputStream(con.getOutputStream());
        wr.writeBytes(urlParameters);
        wr.flush();
        wr.close();
        int responseCode = con.getResponseCode();
        System.out.println("\nSending 'POST' request to URL : " + url);
        System.out.println("Post parameters : " + urlParameters);
        System.out.println("Response Code : " + responseCode);
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));
        String inputLine;
        StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();
        while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
            response.append(inputLine);
        }
        in.close();
        return response.toString();
    }
```

It compiles fine but it won't run. Un the manifest, the Internet permission is present.
It says (in logcat)

```
12-24 14:59:31.028 E/AndroidRuntime(30941): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.fliife.bitvisitorbot/com.fliife.bitvisitorbot.MainActivity}: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
```

What can I do ?

Answer (score 0):

This exception is thrown when an application attempts to perform a networking operation on its main thread because Network operations can involve unpredictable delays. To prevent this from causing a poor user experience, always perform network operations on a separate thread from the UI. The `AsyncTask` class provides one of the simplest ways to fire off a new task from the UI thread.

See: [`AsyncTask`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html):

Just for your information, this is only thrown for applications targeting the Honeycomb SDK or higher. Applications targeting earlier SDK versions are allowed to do networking on their main event loop threads, but it's heavily discouraged.

Answer (score 0):

do the network operation in another thread. in android you can't perform network operatinos on ui thread
refer this example program http://www.androidhive.info/2011/10/android-making-http-requests/

Answer (score 0):

You can not post request on main thread, that means you should post your request async.you can use AsyncTask to make your request execute async, this article is for your reference : https://developer.android.com/training/basics/network-ops/connecting.html

Answer (score 0):

You need an AsyncTask

```
public class Start extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String>{

    protected void onPreExecute() {
        dialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this); //your activity
        dialog.setTitle("Downloading data in progress");
        dialog.setMessage("Wait few seconds...");
        dialog.show();
    }

    protected String doInBackground(String... urls){

        // inside this method you must call your post() method
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(final String result) {

          dialog.dismiss();
       // inside this one you can update your items

    }
}
```

And call this:

```
new Start().execute();
```